# Adding formatted value to plot title in Stata

Tags: stata

I have variables, `y` and `x`, and I have run a regression to obtain the slope of the regression line. I can retrieve the p value (and other parameters) from the regression model using the method described in https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0800700408, such as:

```
regress y x
local t = _b[x]/_se[x]
local p = 2*ttail(e(df_r),abs(`t'))
```

I want to produce a plot of the same data with a line predictor such as:

```
graph twoway (lfitci x y) (scatter x y), note("Simple regression p value = `p'")
```

However, in the above case, the p value that is presented in the plot's note area is expressed to full precision (and without the leading zero). How can I restrict the number of decimal places in the plot to a sensible number? I've tried including %9.3f but haven't been able to work out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local p : di %04.3f `p'
```

If you want spaces in front, put spaces in front.

Examples of similar technique can be found inside the code for `aaplot` on SSC.